# Dynamically generate several multi-paged surveys

Tags: php, dynamically-generated, survey

I am creating a tool to evaluate other players in a computer game. After each match, each player is asked five questions about the other players in the game. I want each of these five questions to display on a new survey page.

I found several neat solutions problems for this online, for instance the one which can be seen [here](https://www.formget.com/multi-page-form-php/). Yet, this example only creates three static pages.

As stated before, I want every player to answer questions about all the other players once a match is finished. This results in a problem, since the number of players in a game is uncertain, meaning that I sometime will have to generate two pages in my survey and other times five pages. The questions on each page will be the same, but I do have to create more pages when there are more players in the game.

At my disposal, I have the number of players, all their information and the questions I want to ask about each player.

I do know how to generate the question I want to give each player. That is not an issue. What is an issue is splitting it to several pages. I cant just do a separate .php-file for each survey page, since the number of pages is changed from game to game.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Updated the post with a lot more information.

Comment: you need to explain your question more, ie give examples and ... show what you have tried.

Comment: I suggest three ways. Firstly, you could ask the user the number of players on the server and loop some php to display the HTML code for the questions that many times. Secondly, depending on the game you may be able to use some sort of API to retrieve the player counts. I can't remember the name of it, but there is a group out there that has their own APIs / graphics to display game server information. Finally, you could use javascript so that when the last question box is filled it shows another set of questions. Then the user can stop when they no longer have answers to put in the box.

Comment: If you could be more specific with what you are asking, like what game, etc. I may be of more help as I have some experience with this kind of stuff.

Comment: A lot more information added /op